# Issue with Hiding Django SECRET_KEY Using environment variables

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am running my programs and Django Project on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance in a virtual environment. The django project is run on an apache server. For purposes of this question I will say that my secret key is 'AAAA'. I have an environment variable set ("SECRET_KEY"). It is properly setup, and when I put:

`import os
print(os.environ['SECRET_KEY'])`

in the python shell, it prints the proper secret key, AAAA. Therefore, I know python is able to access the proper environment variable. In settings.py, when `SECRET_KEY='AAAA'`, the project works, and everything executes properly. However when I change this to: `SECRET_KEY=os.environ['SECRET_KEY']` the server doesn't work (500 Internal Server Error).

Everything seems like it should work. Any suggestions or ideas on what I missed here?

Comment: Are you running your shell with the exact same environment variables as the django process? Where are you setting the environment variable?

Comment: I believe so, I ran a python. script in the same directory as a test which printed the result of the environment variable and it was the right result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to add a default state to the os.environ.get like so:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'mmglfamx3n927*93$ks#r)h%*a(@))vb7*=2q$&z(=6@q&*ghj')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this `SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')` to get environment variables in my projects.

Another thing that you can do is print the env variable in the terminal server to make sure it’s available for the application.

Regards,

Comment: I did this and it was available in terminal. I tried that method of acesing the secret key and it had similar results

Comment: Hey, which one did you do?